# Save list of CGPoints using NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nsset, cgpoint

I have a bunch of CGPoints from a CCTMXLayer I want to save to NSUserDefaults but cannot seem to figure out an elegant way of doing so.

Originally I was hoping to save an NSDictionary with an NSMutableSet for a value containing several NSValues (valueWithCGPoint). From what I can tell neither NSMutableSet or NSValue is supported by NSUserDefaults.

At this point I am considering saving the x&y values of the CGPoint as a string and just converting it back and forth as needed.

Comment: Have you considered just using an NSKeyedArchiver to a file? (Rather than using NSUserDefaults.)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There exists a pair of functions `NSStringFromCGPoint` and `CGPointFromString`. You can use these to produce an array of strings representing the points for serialization, and then convert back when you're finished.

Comment: Remarkable! I had no idea these functions existed. Always finding out new facets of objective-c.

Answer (score 1):

Box them in `NSValue` objects.  Once they're in there, you can write the `NSValues` out to disk (since they conform to `<NSCoding>`) or put them in `NSUserDefaults` or whatever.

Comment: This is exactly my problem. I am trying to store an NSArray (or NSSet...I have tried both) of NSValues using NSUserDefaults but keep receiving an error: [NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value

Comment: Property lists don't use <NSCoding>. NSValue objects cannot be written to plists.

Comment: Oh duh, sorry.  Yes, you'll have to use an `NSKeyedArchiver` to convert the `NSValues` into `NSDatas` (or an `NSArray` into an `NSData`)